# How to lookup for a value within multiple key values pairs

Tags: mule, dataweave, mulesoft, mule4, anypoint-studio

I have an array of objects which contains products ID and product name after they were created, but the array may contains the products that were not created successfully and it returns the original payload before the creation of the product with the attributes that failed:

```
[
   {
      "product_name":"",
      "product_id":"1"
   },
   {
      "product_name":"",
      "product_id":"2"
   },
   {
      "failed_products":[
         {
            "product_id":"3",
            "attribute_1":"Error in value: attribute_1",
            "attribute_2":""
         },
         {
            "product_id":"4",
            "attribute_1":"Error in value: attribute_1",
            "attribute_2":"Error in value: attribute_2"
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

I have to return an array of objects for the products that were successful plus the products that failed giving the reason that they failed on an attribute called "error":

Expected output:

```
[
   {
      "product_name":"",
      "product_id":"1",
      "error":""
   },
   {
      "product_name":"",
      "product_id":"2",
      "error":""
   },
   {
      "product_name":"",
      "product_id":"3",
      "error":"Error in value: attribute_1"
   },
   {
      "product_name":"",
      "product_id":"2",
      "error":"Error in value: attribute_1 and Error in value: attribute_2"
   }
]
```

- The error message could be in multiples attributes

How to build the final response?

Answer (score 3):

Decompose the problem in its parts. First process the attribute that failed and not failed separately. Then map each element to add or modify its attributes to match the expected output. Assuming all attributes in failed products that are not the product_id are error attributes (you could use filterObject() instead) we just get a list of their values and join them.

```js
%dw 2.0
output application/json
---
payload 
    filter !(namesOf($) contains "failed_products") 
    map ($ ++ {error:""})
++
(payload
    filter (namesOf($) contains "failed_products") 
    flatMap (
        $.failed_products map((item) -> { 
            product_name: "",
            product_id: item.product_id,
            error: valuesOf((item- "product_id") filterObject ($$ as String startsWith  "attribute_")) filter (!isEmpty($)) joinBy " and "
        })
       
    )
)
```

Output:

```json
[
  {
    "product_name": "",
    "product_id": "1",
    "error": ""
  },
  {
    "product_name": "",
    "product_id": "2",
    "error": ""
  },
  {
    "product_name": "",
    "product_id": "3",
    "error": "Error in value: attribute_1"
  },
  {
    "product_name": "",
    "product_id": "4",
    "error": "Error in value: attribute_1 and Error in value: attribute_2"
  }
]
```

Comment: This is working fine thank you! The only thing, my bad I didn't specify but the values for the elements within  failed_products won't be "" instead they will have values, so I can't filter them by isEmpty

Comment: I changed my answer to use filterObject() to leave only keys that start with "attribute_" before filtering by isEmpty(). It will be less fragile to this kind of issues anyway so it is a better solution.